# custom map service mapguide openlayers

Tags: service, dictionary, openlayers, mapguide

Recently got started on MapGuide. Kind of lost. The amount of information available on the web is overwhleming.
My requirement is to use custom maps of a campus and building and navigate from a campus view to the floor levels and floor plans of that building.
Please let me know how can I create a map service with my building images using MapGuide.
Also want to use OpenLayers to render it on the browser.

Pl let me know.

Regards
Vish.

Comment: First of all you need to create/setup map feature on mapguide then set up the feature layer on openlayers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some information about using MapGuide wth Openlayers

http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/CodeSamples/JavaScript/OpenlayersExample

Answer (score 1):

That link loops one back around to an open layers example that does not address proper use or even an example of using WFS.

I have been looking and asking for a VALID (complete) example of using a MapGuide WFS as an open layers vector source.

No one has yet provided a working sample.